# Character converter between languages

Tags: localization, special-characters

Is there such a thing?

I want to convert a text with Latin characters to a text with characters in Chinese, Greek and so on (not translate, just convert).

Comment: Like [Google Transliteration](http://www.google.com/transliterate/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [Google Transliteration](http://www.google.com/transliterate/).

> Google Transliteration offers an option for converting Roman characters to their phonetic equivalent in your language. Note that this is not the same as translation -- it is the sound of the words that are converted from one alphabet to the other, not their meaning. For example, typing "hamesha" transliterates into Hindi as: [image] and typing "salaam" transliterates into Persian as: [image]

Comment: Beware that transliteration is culture-dependent. Google Transliteration uses some variants of transliteration schemes used in English. They need not conform to standards, still less to schemes used in other languages. And the schemes that Google uses seem to be undocumented and complicated. The odds are that if you need reliable, documented transliteration, you need to code it yourself.